# FPDF Header and Footer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, fpdf

I've install FPDF on Laravel 4.

I use this code to try FPDF but the functions `Header()` and `Footer()` don't work

```
class PDF extends Fpdf
{
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);

        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);

        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);

        // Title
        $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');

        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);

    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);

        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);

        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}


// Instanciation of inherited class

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);

$pdf->Output();
exit;
```

This is the result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70804756/doc%20(3).pdf

Can someone point me where the error is?

Comment: You should be creating a new PDF instance, not Fpdf.

Comment: I changed that part, But not work. I saw that if I add $pdf->Header(); call work function Header. In documentation of FPDF there is write:"This example makes use of the Header() and Footer() methods to process page headers and footers. They are called automatically. They already exist in the FPDF class but do nothing, therefore we have to extend the class and override them. "

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write a new class which extends FPDF and put your Header & Footer methods in there.

```
class PDF extends FPDF {

  function Header() {}
  function Footer() {}
}
```

Then in your controller...

```
new PDF();
```