# How to add table header to all pages using FPDF and WriteHTML

Tags: php, html-table, fpdf

I'm generating a large table (more than one page) using FPDF in Landscape mode and need to add table header in all pages. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
require('html_table.php');

$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

$html='<table border="1">';
for ($i=0; $i<300; $i++)
{
    $html.='<tr><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td><td>hello</td></tr>';
}
$html.='</table>';

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output("reporte_semanal_".date("d").date("m").date("Y")."_".date("H")."H".date("i")."M".date("s")."S".".pdf", "D");
```

Comment: I found two links: [fpdf](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/header.htm) and [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244406/fpdf-header-and-footer)

Comment: It works perfectly adding Header() method, thank you very much @SebastianHallin