# How to set the header and footer in PDF table using the fpdf library in php

Tags: php

I have created the table using the fpdf library. and now i want to set the header and footer in the table.so how it is possible.please see the screen shot for more detail.i want show the name of the company and also name of reciever and also some more detail in header .[image]

```
// Colored table
    private function FancyTable($header, $data) {
        // Colors, line width and bold font
        $this->fpdf->SetFillColor(255, 0, 0);
        $this->fpdf->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->fpdf->SetDrawColor(128, 0, 0);
        $this->fpdf->SetLineWidth(.1);
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('', '', 1);
        // Header
        $w = array(20, 100, 20, 20, 30);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++) {
            $this->fpdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C', true);
        }
        $this->fpdf->Ln();
        // Color and font restoration
        $this->fpdf->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
        $this->fpdf->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->fpdf->SetFont('', '', 10);
        // Data
        $fill = false;
        $this->data_array = array();
        $this->getdata($data, 0);
        foreach ($this->data_array as $row) {
            if (strlen($row[1]) > 50) {
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[0], 5, $row[0], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[1], 5, substr($row[1], 0, 50), 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[2], 5, $row[2], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[3], 5, $row[3], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[4], 5, $row[4], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Ln();
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[0], 5, $row[0] = '', 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[1], 5, substr($row[1], 50), 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[2], 5, $row[2] = '', 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[3], 5, $row[3] = '', 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[4], 5, $row[4] = '', 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Ln();
                $fill = !$fill;
            } else {
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[0], 5, $row[0], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[1], 5, $row[1], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[2], 5, $row[2], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[3], 5, $row[3], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Cell($w[4], 5, $row[4], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
                $this->fpdf->Ln();
                $fill = !$fill;
            }
        }
        // Closing line
        $this->fpdf->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new class extend to FPDF class. please refer the following links the solution is there

[new class extend to FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244406/fpdf-header-and-footer)

[FPDF docs add header and footer](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm)

Comment: link only answers are discouraged